# Trace of a product of 2 matrices

Tags: matrices, trace, matrix-decomposition, matrix-rank

I have the following problem. Let $\textbf{Y} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times q} \; n>q, \textbf{H} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ such that $\textbf{H}$ is idempotent ($\textbf{H}^{2} = \textbf{H}$) and symmetric, positive definite whose trace is $p_{\gamma}$ where $0 \leq p_{\gamma} < q < n$. Furthermore let's assume that the product $$\textbf{Y}^\top \textbf{Y}$$ is invertible.

I'd like to know whether or not I'd be able to find the trace of the following matrix product: $$(\textbf{Y}^\top \textbf{H} \textbf{Y}) (\textbf{Y}^\top \textbf{Y})^{-1}$$
And if not, whether I'd be able to bound it in some way given what I already know.

Thanks in advance

Comment: We have that trace is invariant under cyclic permutations of matrix products, giving us
$$\mbox{trace}(Y^THY(Y^TY)^{-1})=\mbox{trace}(HY(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^T).$$
We then notice that $P=Y(Y^TY)^{-1}Y^T$ is a projection matrix with
$$\mbox{trace}(P)=\mbox{rank}(Y).$$

Comment: Hi! Thanks for that. Unfortunately, I'm not seeing how this helps me to find the trace of the matrix product HP?